# About Ito's rule

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a questions about Exercise3.3.25 at Karatzas&Shreve"Brownian Motion and Stochastic Integral".

$W=\{W_t, F_t; 0\leq t<\infty\}$ is a standard, one-dimensional Brownian motion and X a measurable, adapted process satisfying
\begin{equation}
E\int_{0}^{T}|X_t|^{2m}dt < \infty
\end{equation} for some real numbers $T > 0$ and $m \geq 1$,
show that
\begin{equation}
E\left|\int_{0}^{T}X_t dW_t\right|^{2m}\leq (m(2m-1))^mT^{m-1}E\int_{0}^{T}|X_t|^{2m}dt
\end{equation}

Hint:
$ \{M_t=\int_{0}^{t} X_sdW_s, F_t; 0\leq t \leq \infty \} $ is martingale, and use Ito's rule for $|M_t|^{2m}$

Why we can use absolute function for Ito's rule.
I think we cannot use it directly bacause abosolute function is not differentiable at 0.

Comment: @Tab1e I know Ito's lemma requiring that the function have twice differentiable. But,$|\cdot|^{2m}$ is not differentiable at 0.

Comment: @Tab1e Thank you! I'll investigate it.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the Ito's lemma can be used directly. See [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606603/exercise-3-3-25-of-karatzas-and-shreve?rq=1).

Comment: @Tab1e yes. $(\cdot)^{2m} $is twice differentiable everywhere. So, the Ito's lemma can be used directly.